# Capture image and prompt for caption on preview screen

Tags: android, image

I want the user to be able to use the capture option on my app (which uses `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`) and then on the preview (where the user has the option to retake, cancel or accept), give them the option to add a caption (I am not trying to embed this caption to the image, just want the user to optionally add a caption that I will save to my DB).

Is there an easy way to do this? Or do I have to take the captured image and once the user selected accept, show the image in another view that I created which has the image and then a `EditText` to add the caption?

Comment: @Harry: But I can't do this from the same view where the retake, cancel and accept option is given, it will happen after I return from that and come back to my activity. One option is to use SurfaceView, but looks like implementing all the camera functionality there is a lot of work. At the moment I am using a new fragment to show the image and ask for the caption, after the user selected accept, however, this is an extra step I am trying to avoid.